# why Page is not available under Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I move aspx views to razor. Some things are not worked (null reference) :

```
Page.RouteData.Values["IdeaType"]
Page.User.IsInRole("Admin")
```

I have to change to:

```
ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["IdeaType"]
ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin")
```

why?
need to import something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Razor's `Page` property returns a page state bag that can pass data between layout pages, content pages, and partial views.
WebForm's `Page` property returns your `Page` instance (it's inherited from the `Control` class).

They're not the same.

In general, WebForms properties and Razor properties are rather different.

Note that Razor pages also have a `User` property; you can just write `User.IsInRole(...)`.

Comment: Thanks! I am updating a MVC2 project to Razor and I was getting a bizarre null error over this! :)